# Proving $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} xy = 0$

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

Seems simple enough, but my notes do something I don't understand.

Question is:

```
prove lim          xy = 0
      (x,y) -> (0,0)
```

The notes say that

```
0 <| (x,y) - (0,0) | < d
implies 0 < |(x, y)| < d
step 3: implies 0 < square root (x^2 + y^2) < d
```

Then does:

```
0 <= (x+y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2
implies 2xy <= x^2 + y^2
implies 2|xy| <= x^2 + y^2
implies |xy| <= x^2 + y^2 / 2 < d/2
```

and chooses `epsilon = d^2 /2 which implies`d^2 = epsilon / 2 which implies to pick `d = square root of (epsilon/2)`.

Im confused on step 3. Why did they take the `square root of (x^2 + y^2)`? How does step 2 imply step 3?

And why was step 3 followed with

```
0 <= (x+y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2
```

Where did that come from?

I was taught to go from |xy - 0| < epsilon and try to make |xy - 0| to something like |(x,y) - (0,0)|

Comment: I think it's easier to just go with the Heine definition of convergence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They took the square root of $x^2+y^2$ because $\bigl\lVert(x,y)\bigr\rVert=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Step 2 implies step 3 because $\bigl\lVert(x,y)-(0,0)\bigr\rVert=\bigl\lVert(x,y)\bigr\rVert$.

Finally, since$$\lvert xy\rvert\leqslant\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}2,\tag1$$then, for every $\varepsilon>0$, if you take $\delta$ such that $\delta=2\varepsilon$, it follows from $(1)$ that$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta\implies\lvert xy\rvert<\varepsilon$. Yes, I know that this is not the same $\delta$ as the one that you mentioned, but I suppose that what matters to you is that *some* $\delta$ will do.

Comment: Okay thanks. So after step 3, how did they get `0 <= (x+y)^2`? How did they know to do `(x+y)^2`? Where did `(x+y)^2` come from?

Comment: What comes after step 3 is **not** a consequence of that step. What they do is to prove inequality $(1)$ and, on order to do that, they take as their starting point the trivial inequality $0\leqslant(x+y)^2$.

Comment: Ah ok, and on the last step before choosing epsilon, how is it known that `(x^2 + y^2)/ 2 < d/2`?

Comment: I was unable to follow that passage. That's why I provided my own choice of $\delta$.